# Jquery sliding panels (again)

Tags: jquery, panel, slide

This is a follow up on a previous question...I was helped out adapting my code (thanks akloboucnik), and have this as an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fE8ks/1/

This example above changed my code to animating the elements width, therefore resulting in a "collapse" and "expand" type of effect.

What I've decided I need to do with the code is to actually animate the left margin to achieve a "sliding" effect.

The very basic example of what I'm trying to do can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wsb22/

So basically what I'm trying to achieve is a combination of them both.  I need to have several divs (just content panels) that are activated by links similar to the first jsfiddle example, but I need to animate the panels by the method of the second jsfiddle example.

I need to have some divs which are all hidden when the page loads, except the first one, and when the additional links are clicked, the current content panel will animate left to be hidden and the panel clicked with then animate right to be shown.  I also need it to where the current panel is active, when that panels link is clicked, it won't animate again.

I hope this makes sense, and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction, as I can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your looking for, but maybe this is it : http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/fE8ks/4/

Comment: Hello, but i have been looking for kind of like that but directions would be horizontal and vertical sliding... can I ask for help or any links that might help, thanks